# C# base constructor determination

Tags: c#

Can I choose a base constructor based on some non-instance related conditions in C#? If I can't, any idea to meet my requirement? Thanks!

```
class X {}

class Y {}

class A {
    public A(X x) {}
    public A(Y y) {}
    // I don't want to add another constructor with an optional argument
}

class B : A {
    private static y = new Y();
    // I want to call different base constructor based on the value of argument `x`
    public B(X x=null) : base(x!=null? (X)x: (Y)y) {} // x, y here doesn't related to any instance
}
```

Comment: @AlexF - It's just the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a [Factory method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)):

> https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method/csharp/example
>
> Factory method is a creational design pattern which solves the problem
> of creating product objects without specifying their concrete classes.
>
> Factory Method defines a method, which should be used for creating
> objects instead of direct constructor call (new operator). Subclasses
> can override this method to change the class of objects that will be
> created.

Here's a good example in C#:

[Factory Method Design Pattern In C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/factory-method-design-pattern-in-c-sharp/)

Comment: For an example of a factory method, see [`WebRequest.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.create). It will return a `WebRequest` reference to a derived class instance based on the protocol of the URL you pass in.

Comment: Thank you @paulsm4, while I understand this design pattern, I expect it can be supported by the language itself instead of having another trick to do that because my requirement is fairly intuitive and basic, with a specific pattern to introduce a wrapper to constructors sounds a trick, rather than a common practice.

Comment: If C# doesn't have this language feature, I'd propose it to see whether they can implement it in C# 3000.0.

Comment: "Design patterns" aren't "tricks".  The issue isn't with "C#" (or .Net): it's OOP 101.  Specifically: 1) A "class" has "state" and "behavior" ("members" and "methods"). 2) You initialize class state with a "constructor".  3) A class may have one or more constructors, and zero or more "custom" constructors.  4) A "parent" class may also have "child subclasses" (aka "inheritence")  Child classes may (optionally) have their *OWN* constructors.  5) A "base constructor" belongs to a parent.  It's firmly associated with that class hierarchy.

Comment: In your case, you might want a Factory.  Or simply have two constructors for "B": `public B(X x)` and `public B(Y y)`.  If the "default null" is important to you, then add a no-arg constructor: `public B() : base (... whatever makes sense to you...) {...}`

Comment: @paulsm4 Thanks for your update. Regarding "Design patterns..." what you said is 100% correct, but not very much related to `Why the language doesn't support to determine base constructor at runtime, or even why the compiler doesn't generate multiple constructors for my case given the fact that I provided the types of arguments to the base constructor`.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question. You cannot, with a factory method, write a constructor `Derived() : someCondition ? base(someValueX) : base() {` and it's not supported to do that as part of a normal constructor either